# missing required keys: [:id] when updating a nested element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

first of all thanks a lot for helping me out.

I am working on a project tool, where i have a project model that has_many project_tasks.  The project_tasks belongs to a project.

I am trying to make a mark as complete action for the project tasks, but i can't seem to get the project_task id in the patch action.

Here is my routes:
(Note that i have a complete action for the project too, but that is working fine)

```
resources :projects do
    resources :project_tasks do
      member do
        patch :complete
      end
    end
    member do
      patch :complete
    end
  end
```

Rake routes

```
complete_project_project_task PATCH  /projects/:project_id/project_tasks/:id/complete(.:format) project_tasks#complete
        project_project_tasks GET    /projects/:project_id/project_tasks(.:format)              project_tasks#index
                              POST   /projects/:project_id/project_tasks(.:format)              project_tasks#create
     new_project_project_task GET    /projects/:project_id/project_tasks/new(.:format)          project_tasks#new
    edit_project_project_task GET    /projects/:project_id/project_tasks/:id/edit(.:format)     project_tasks#edit
         project_project_task GET    /projects/:project_id/project_tasks/:id(.:format)          project_tasks#show
                              PATCH  /projects/:project_id/project_tasks/:id(.:format)          project_tasks#update
                              PUT    /projects/:project_id/project_tasks/:id(.:format)          project_tasks#update
                              DELETE /projects/:project_id/project_tasks/:id(.:format)          project_tasks#destroy
             complete_project PATCH  /projects/:id/complete(.:format)                           projects#complete
                     projects GET    /projects(.:format)                                        projects#index
                              POST   /projects(.:format)                                        projects#create
                  new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                                    projects#new
                 edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                               projects#edit
                      project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                                    projects#show
                              PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                                    projects#update
                              PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                                    projects#update
                              DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                                    projects#destroy
```

The View:

```
<%= link_to '', complete_project_project_task_path(@project, project_task.id), class: "glyphicon glyphicon-ok", id: "complete-#{project_task.id}", method: :patch %>
```

And the controller action:

```
def complete
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @project_task = project.project_task.find(params[:id])
    if @project_task.completed_at.blank?
      @project_task.update_attribute(:completed_at, Time.now)
      flash[:success] = 'Task Completed!'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @project_task.update_attribute(:completed_at, '')
      flash[:info] = 'Task Updated!'
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

The error i am getting is :
No route matches {:action=>"complete", :controller=>"project_tasks", :id=>nil, :project_id=>"26"} missing required keys: [:id]

In the link_to i add 2 arguments, the @project (to get the project id) and the project_task.id.
It seems that i am getting the project id correct, but not the project_task.id.
I tried to change the controller action to @project_task = ProjectTask.find(params[:id]) but without any luck.
(I also tried a few things out with different arguments in the link_to)
I am not sure how to retrieve that, but i hope one of you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you update the question with the output from `rake routes`

Comment: Yes, it is updated now.

Comment: What happens if instead of using "complete_project_project_task_path(@project, project_task.id)" you give it the following path (inside of link_to) "/projects/#{@project.id}/project_tasks/#{project_task.id}/complete" ?

Do you still get the same error?

Comment: That is actually working!
Then when i click the link i get the error : No route matches [PATCH] "/projects/26/project_tasks/1/c%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bomplete"

But i think that confirms that the link_to is missing the project_task.id, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i figured out what the problem was.
I had 2 versions of the @project_task instance, which created the conflict.  (both from the form and from the complete action)
So i added

```
<% @project.project_tasks.select(&:persisted?).each do |project_task| %>
```

And the fix was to add the &:persisted? in order to only display saved objects.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `project_task` variable in the view is not correctly set up. Your code should something like this:

```
<% @project.project_tasks.each do |project_task| %>
  <%= link_to '', complete_project_project_task_path(@project, project_task.id), class: "glyphicon glyphicon-ok", id: "complete-#{project_task.id}", method: :patch %>
<% end %>
```

(This considers your `Project` model `has_many :project_tasks`).

If you are setting it up correctly, can you provide the complete view and its controller action?

Comment: I just double checked the associations and they are correct on both the project.rb and the project_task.rb

I don't think the problem is with the view, since it is showing the project_tasks (and i can create them too), but only it only occur after i added the complete link to the tasks.

The project_tasks are rendered as a partial like this :
<%= render @project.project_tasks %>

Comment: Can you print project_task.inspect above your link_to (inside the template)? See if you're getting the right object there.

Also, inside of your _complete_ controller method, how come you're referencing _project.project_task_ and not _@project.project_task_? (since you're setting your variable to _@project_in the line above it)

Comment: I get the right object with the _@project_task.inspect : #<ProjectTask id: 1, title: "wqeq", user_id: 1, project_id: 26, completed_at: nil, 

Regarding the _@project.project_task that is one error!  I changed it to refer to the _@project.project_task instead, since the instance variable is set to the current project just above in that controller action.

I think the error is at the link_to, but not the second argument after the path, since the error says that project_task.id is empty.
I tried with both project.project_task.id and @project.project_task.id .. but without luck

Comment: I changed the link_to to this : 
  <%= link_to '', complete_project_project_task_path(@project, @project.project_tasks), class: "glyphicon glyphicon-ok", id: "complete-#{project_task.id}", method: :patch %>

Now the page is loading, but the link gives me an error : Couldn't find ProjectTask with 'id'=#<ProjectTask::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f93788e9fc8>

I wonder, how do i find the project.project_task id in the controller action?
Because this one is not correct @project_task = ProjectTask.find(params[:id])

Comment: If `@project_task` is rendering correctly, why don't you use it instead of `project_task` in your `link_to`? Like this:
`<%= link_to '', complete_project_project_task_path(@project, @project_task), class: "glyphicon glyphicon-ok", id: "complete-#{project_task.id}", method: :patch %> `
By the way, you shouldn't use `@project.project_tasks` in your `link_to`, as you are giving an array of objects for the `complete` action instead of a single one.

Comment: @project_task is not rendering correctly in the view.
I am still getting the error with missing id.
I tried a few things and noticed that if i just add the arguments <%= link_to '', complete_project_project_task_path(@project, 1) %> then it gets the correct path in the link.  (But it only works for the one with the id of 1 of course)
Outside the link_to i can get the task id by adding <%= project_task.id %>, but inside the link_to it is like the value is empty or nil.
I am getting the _@project without problems.
The path is correct /project/24/project_task/XX where the XX are missing